# How to return multiple lists of row names as a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 25 lists in an object `lists` that I subset from 25 RNAseq data with correlation values less than -0.4.

They are of different lengths and different row names, as shown below.

```
head(lists)

$Sample1
               Sample1
CWC27        -0.4000203
MCM3AP-AS1   -0.4000415
TAF1D        -0.4000936
SOX21        -0.4003181
PRPF6        -0.4003951
TYSND1       -0.4005185

$Sample2
            Sample2
ZEB1      -0.4000603
BRD7      -0.4001116
AP2B1     -0.4003789
CDH10     -0.4005792

$Sample3
            Sample3
 WIZ      -0.4125093
 RAB22A   -0.4175807
 TMEM143  -0.4176838
 HNRNPUL1 -0.4187072
 SOBP     -0.4194346
```

I wanted to just return the row names but not the values, like

```
Sample1       Sample2      Sample3
CWC27         ZEB1         WIZ
MCM3AP-AS1    BRD7         RAB22A
TAF1D         AP2B1        TMEM143
SOX21         CDH10        HNRNPUL1
PRPF6                      SOBP
TYSND1
```

I was lost because I am not familiar with R. I tried something like

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(lapply(lists, unlist), "[",
                   unique(unlist(c(sapply(lists,rownames))))))
```

It did not work, returning

```
  Sample1       Sample2      Sample3
       NA            NA          NA
       NA            NA          NA
       NA            NA          NA
       NA            NA          NA
       NA            NA          NA
       NA            NA          NA
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: try `lapply(lists, function(l) rownames(l))`

Comment: Yes, it did return the row names. But could you show me how to bind them together as a data.frame for export `write.table`?

Comment: I don't have access to an interpreter atm, try `as.data.frame(lapply(lists, rownames))` You may need to transpose

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Giving the following error `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 4, 5...`

Comment: `as.data.frame(lapply(lists, function(l) rownames(l)))` if that is tilted from what you want to see try `t(as.data.frame(lapply(lists, function(l) rownames(l))))`

Comment: It gave the same error as above. Looks like it cannot write as data.frame because of different lengths.

Comment: You can use something like this to automatically pad each column with `NA`: `cbind.data.frame(lapply(lapply(lists, rownames), "length<-", max(sapply(ll, length))))`. The trick here is that `lapply(x) <- n` is a way to force a vector to be a given length, filling with `NA` if necessary.

Comment: @Alexey. Your code is heading the right direction. But for some reason, it gives only the first row of data, like just CWC27, ZEB1 and WIZ for samples 1-3. Do I have to add something on `"length<-"`? This is the code that I used `cbind.data.frame(lapply(lapply(lists, rownames), "length<-", max(sapply(lists, length))))`.

Comment: Bah, that was a typo on my part. Probably easier to break into pieces:
`names_list <- lapply(lists, rownames)`
`names_list2 <- lapply(names_list, "length<-", max(sapply(names_list, length)))`
`data.frame(names_list2)`

Comment: @Alexey. That does the trick! Thanks so much! Could you post it to the answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down:

First, grab the rownames of each object

```
names_list <- lapply(lists, rownames)
```

Then, get the length of the longest list.

```
max_length <- max(sapply(names_list, length))
```

Then, set the length of each list to the max length of any item in the list. Any shorter lists are padded with `NA`s.

```
names_list <- lapply(names_list, "length<-", max_length)
```

Finally, convert to a `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(names_list)
```